# How do I search, increment, and replace integer substrings in a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, replace, gsub

I have a lot of documents that look like this:

```
foo_1 foo_2

foo_3

bar_1 foo_4 ...
```

And I want to convert them by taking all instances of `foo_[X]` and replacing each of them with `foo_[X+1]`. In this example:

```
foo_2 foo_3

foo_4

bar_1 foo_5 ...
```

Can I do this with gsub and a block? If not, what's the cleanest approach? I'm really looking for an elegant solution because I can always brute force it, but feel there's some regex trickery worth learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Ruby (at all), but something similar to this should work:

```
"foo_1 foo_2".gsub(/(foo_)(\d+)/) {|not_needed| $1 + ($2.to_i + 1).to_s}
```

---

LE: I actually made it work: http://codepad.org/Z5ThOvTr

Comment: Thanks! I didn't consider matching (foo_) and reusing it in the block.

Comment: You can leave out `|not_needed|` entirely.

Comment: @Wayne Oh, OK. But I'll leave it like that to show that it is available but not used.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the numbers following foo_ to be changed

```
str.gsub(/(?<=foo_)\d+/) {|num| num.to_i+1}
```

---

Note: Look-behinds will only work in versions or Ruby >= 1.9.

Comment: Actually, lookbehinds _can work_ if your version of Ruby is >= 1.9. 1.9 adds some interesting new features and a wonderful regexp engine called Oniguruma (which is also used by PHP5 mb regex).

Comment: @Phrogz. Unfortunately, most people are still using Ruby 1.8, which can handle lookahead, but not look-behind assertions…

Comment: I removed my comment as I clearly don't have enough info about Ruby to make an informed comment. Knowing that regular-expressions.info is a reliable source I, wrongly, assumed it to be up to date. Also maybe you should add a comment in the answer to specify for what version your code works.

Comment: @Phrogz For the record, the project on which I'm working is using ruby-1.8.7 (not my choice). It's an enterprise deployment with about 25 developers involved in various aspects of development and maintenance. While I'm sure all of the developers in the group would prefer ruby-1.9, there are no plans to upgrade anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler is just using .next

```
"foo_1".next #=> foo_2
"bar_1 foo_1".next #=> bar_1 foo_2
```

So, you could simplify your regex and block like so

```
"bar_1 foo_2".gsub(/\bfoo_\d+\b/) {|f| f.next }
```